# Can not display Django models on Homepage

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am creating a portfolio test site. When I try to import models in home.html from views.py, which I imported from models.py, error displays on my website page (no such column: portfolio_project.title). Help would be greatly appreciated!

models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='portfolio/images/')
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Project
def home(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'portfolio/home.html', {'projects':projects})
```

home.html file

```
<h1>This is Home!</h1>

{% for project in projects %}


{{project.title}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you remember to `makemigrations` and then `migrate`?

Comment: Did you check identation and run migrations?

Comment: Oh, I corrected title variable indentation in here, it is correct on my project though

Comment: Oh, yes I forgot to to makemigrations and migrate. What a silly mistake, sorry for wasting your time...